# Collecting data for an interactive game map

Tags: c#, maps, data-collection

I'm trying to create an interactive map for a project, and I already have created the basic core engine that allow me to set an image (no tiles yet, but it's coming), handle the zoom and place interests points wherever I want.
My issue now is collecting data from actual games like Genshin or the new Avatar game.

I know both of them already have existing maps, and I already asked the creators for their help. I'll be sure to post here the way I they give me or the one I found to collect the data as soon as I have one !

*I know that unauthorized access, reverse engineering, or extraction of data from games can violate the terms of service, end-user license agreements, or intellectual property rights of these games, but if people already have their own interactive maps for this 2 games, I guess I'm safe as long as I use the same way they used :)*

Thanks in advance for your help !